# How to manipulate tables in php

Tags: php, arrays, list

Please I have the fowlloing code :

```
foreach($global as $item) 
    {   
        $item_array[] = array
                        (
                            '0'  => value($this->elem[0], $item),
                            '1'   => value($this->elem[1], $item),
                            '2' => value($this->elem[2], $item),
                            '3'  => value($this->elem[3], $item),
                            '4' => value($this->elem[4], $item)
                        );
    }
```

And I want to simplify it as the folloing :

```
foreach($global as $item) 
    {       
        $i=0;
        array_push($item_array[], value($this->elem[$i], $item) );
        $i++; 
             }
```

This code gives me an arror because of "$item_array[]" which is necessary for my script. What can I do ?

Note : I'm very newbie to PHP. Thanks.

Comment: drop the `[]` in your `array_push` call. You can use `array_push`, $array[]` or `$array[index]` when adding elements to a PHP array (but not combined).

Comment: **What** error is it giving you?

Comment: The error is : Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: When I drop [], my script doesn't work !

Comment: can you `serialize($global)` and add the content here ... let me see what you are working with

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete [] and put the $i=0 outside the for loop.